# Samsung MTP Requires "Allow" access to files every time when connecting to Mac

Tags: samsung, file-transfer, mtp, macos

I have a Samsung M51 device running Android 12 and a MacBook Air M1 running macOS Monterey. I have installed Android File Transfer App and tried to transfer files between the devices. The issue is that The application requires permission to access the files every single time I connect the phone to the mac.

I hope this is a problem with SAMSUNG devices since programs like OpenMTP instructs you to select allow every time you connect the device.

I was wondering if there is a way to make the Samsung device remember the computer it was connected to.

I have already tried clearing data and cache of USBSettings MTPapps and force stopping them in my Samsung Device.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: AFAIK the MTP protocol has no (reliable) way to identify the host you are connected to. So the only way is to ask every time or to automatically allow access. Only the adb protocol (can be enabled in Developer options) has the option to identify a computer and thus allow to trust for some months (or optionally permanently). But ADB requires different programs on host side.

Comment: Thanks @Robert for the reply. Even though I understand what you are saying. I found out that only latest devices (Android 11,12 ) of Samsung are facing this issue. It should be noted that I didn't have the opportunity to test latest devices of other manufacturers. I had the opportunity to test older devices of Samsung (Android 9) and Others and haven't got this issue. It connects to computer directly after the first time. If you don't mind, Why is that?

Comment: I have the same issue and it would be great if there is a solution to that.... can't manage files for quite a while...